# Get arguments name of function in llvm IR

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to read the name of the arguments of fucntion IR LLVM, I have the following function define:

```
define void @vecadd(i32, float* nocapture readonly, float* nocapture readonly, float* nocapture) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
```

As we see, the argument has no name, if we look at call function in main function we see the arguments name (a, b and c):

```
call void @vecadd(i32 10, float* getelementptr inbounds ([10 x float], [10 x float]* @a, i64 0, i64 0), float* getelementptr inbounds ([10 x float], [10 x float]* @b, i64 0, i64 0), float* nonnull %3)
```

The problem is, how can I get arguments name from the instruction inside define function because I just have the instructions in define function.

Any idea please?

Comment: When you look at the call, you see the name of the values that you provide as the actual arguments - not the name of the formal arguments/parameters. Since the function can be called arbitrarily many times with different arguments (which have different names), it's not clear which ones you'd want. For example, what if there was a second call to `@vecadd` with arguments `@c` and `@d`?

Comment: That good question, but if we suppose that we call the function just once, how I get the names? I tried callInst and getCalledFunbction() but it does not work, maybe I do not how to use them, for example I used one instruction from define function like this `dyn_cast<CallInst>(inst)`, do you have a idea to access to call function from define function?